# Server Error 500 while authentication | Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-authentication, django-auth-models

Having server error 500 when trying to save user record and authenticating him to the dashboard.

**CODE**

```
user_id = 5
unique_username = "kashif"
user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
user.unique_username = unique_username
user.is_active = True
useremail = user.email
user.save()

user = auth.authenticate(request, email=useremail, password=password)
auth.login(request, user)

return redirect('home')
```

**EROOR**

```
Server Error (500)
```

[image]

**CODE EXPLANATION**

- In above code, user email is already stored in database.
- Also, Django default login from username is overridden with Email.
- So here, getting username from user via HTML for, after storing username then getting user email and password from database to authenticate user.
- But having error on authentication line.

**NOTE**

Project is uploaded at app.barter.monster

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?>

Comment: All which is displayed is thie server error. Nothing in even console. Also you can check traceback by your self if any I can't find at app.barter.monster

Comment: If you can replicate this locally, you can set `DEBUG = True` to see the traceback

Comment: Issue solved. Thanks